# Fix the orientation of UISplitViewController to landscape

Tags: ipad, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller

I am fixing the orientation of the uisplitView controller to landscape in code but it does not show the detailView controller it hides that view is there a way in which forcibly do only landscape orientation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample project with UISplitViewControllers, UINavigationControllers and UITabBars:
https://github.com/alexth/TBSV